# Accessing command line arguements Installshield Installation Designer UI

Tags: installation, installshield, installshield-2015

I am working on an installer project which doesn't have the install shield script. Everything is done using Installshield Designer UI. Is there any way I can pass command line arguments to the installer and access those values from Installshield Designer UI and write those values into a registry key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the public property assigned to the user inputs in Designer UI. You can pass values to those properties(e.g. DBSERVER=sqlservername) from command-line.

Go to User Interface > Dialogs > All Dialogs

All the standard and custom UI are listed here. Expand the one which are being used in your installation. Clicking on Language will display UI. Select the user input.On the right pane, there should be a field called property.

In Installshield, Go to System Configuration > Registry. You can create  custom registry keys/subkeys and can pass the public property as data to the value. (e.g. DbServer REG_SZ [DBSERVER]).

Comment: Thanks, Can you please tell me where to look out for that. I am pretty new to this Installshield @Viv